# non convex optimisation

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

\begin{eqnarray}
  {\textbf{maximise}} \hspace{2mm} Ar^{-(a+b)} + Br^{-(a+b+c)}-C \nonumber 
 \end{eqnarray}
such that,
 \begin{eqnarray}
c= l(h-m_{0}) \nonumber\\
m_{1} \leq h \leq m_{2} \nonumber\\
a+ b \geq m_{3} \nonumber \\
a\leq l(h-m_{4}) \nonumber \\
b \leq l(h-m_{5}) \nonumber \\
\tan\theta=\frac{m_{6}+m_{7}a/b}{m_{8}+m_{9}a/b}  \nonumber \\
h= \frac{(n_{1}-n_{2}\cos(\theta-k_{0}))+a/b(n_{3}-n_{4}\cos(\theta-k_{2}))}{Z(1+a/b)} \nonumber \\
0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi \nonumber
 \end{eqnarray}

The decision variables are $a,b,c,h,\theta$. All other variables are constants.
Objective functions is strictly convex on a,b,c. 
The problem domain is not convex.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. This site supports [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which will help make your question a bit more legible. Please see the link for some quick intro on how to take advantage of this capability.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dummy variables to get rid of functional inequalities and then you may use Kuhn-Tucker conditions. If you are still interested in the solution I can provide further info...